# 'can't find '__ main __' module' in command prompt

Tags: python, command-line-interface

So I was following the tutorial on some basic set-up (cloning the folder onto my own pc) of a project

> If you have chosen to install python (and already set up PATH variable
> for python.exe) then follow the instructions:
>
> Open the command prompt and change the directory to the project folder
> as mentioned above by running the below command
>
> `cd C:/your cloned project folder path goes here/`
>
> then run the below command
>
> `python.exe C:/your cloned project folder path goes here/`

And then I got:

```
C:\Users\user_name\project_name>python.exe C:\Users\user_name\project_name

C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_abc1d2efgh3i4\python.exe: can't find '__main__' module in 'C:\\Users\\user_name\\project_name'
```

when I entered the second command. (note: I cloned the project folder to \user_name\project_name).

Yet I can't find much helpful information for this problem as it usually appears within python but not the command prompt of the computer itself. I have checked that I did set up the PATH variable for python.exe. And the path I entered for the 2 commands is the same. What may be wrong and how do I fix it?

Here is the cap screen of the content I was running, if helpful. The parts covered by blue are just user_name and project_name and some irrelevant information.
[click to see cap screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f50rZ.png) (I am not allowed to embed pictures in posts as I haven't earned enough reputation.)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Would you mind editing your post and showing us the contents of the Python file you're running?

Comment: I suggest creating a new `hello.py` file with `print("Hello, World!")` and trying to run it. Do you get a similar error? This will help narrow own the problem to see if it's the python installation or the project that you cloned.

Comment: did you try `python -m /path/to/module`?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice The python itself works fine. I installed the python a long time ago and it has been great in use, so i guess it's the latter case.

Comment: I think the problem is that `C:\\Users\\user_name\\project_name` is a folder. You must specify a `.py` file not a folder, for example: `python.exe C:\project/my_file.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see this error because `C:\Users\user_name\project_name` is a folder and python doesn't know how to handle it. Instead, you need to specify the name of a python script. These are files that usually end with a `.py` extension.